# Downloading the data from LAADS using Python wget code equal to the wget command

Tags: python, wget

I'm trying to download data from LAADS using [Python Script](https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/tools-and-services/data-download-scripts/#python) 
and using the order link [Data page](https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/archive/orders/). But I couldn't download the data.

Now I want to create the script on python using [wget](https://pypi.org/project/wget/) /or other packages. I have used this line of codes and the output is given:
[wget code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Odf9U.png), I couldn't understand the error message. I also dont know how and where to use the [App Key](https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/tools-and-services/data-download-scripts/#appkeys).

So, finally, I want the necessary suggestion to create the python script which gives the output as [wget command](https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/tools-and-services/data-download-scripts/#wget) in the command-line window.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the code snippets (what you have tried, what were the results) inline in your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for details.

Answer (score 0):

From your link, it seems that you didn't escape the backslash characters in you `wget.download` statement, therefore python thinks that `'...\Nov18'` should be a `\N{name}` [unicode literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals), which is malformed - hence the complaint. Try

```
wget.download(url2, out='D:\\Data\\AOD\\S18M19\\Nov18')
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion, I tried the command you suggested, but it is not working. I must add the "App Key" to download, but I am not getting where to insert the app key in the command. Please help me with this.

Comment: Well, to use the app key, you will have to set the `Authorization` http header [accordingly](https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/tools-and-services/data-download-scripts/#how-to-use-app-key). The `wget` library you use does not seem to support that. Try using [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) instead.